# Audio jack issues with Dell latittude 7410

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, motherboard, dell-latitude

My laptop audio jack is not working. So even if I plug my ear phones into audio jack.
The sound still comes from the laptop speakers. I have tried every imaginable thing.
At one time dell decided to replace my motherboard. But then the technician discovered
that my ear phones started working suddenly and then stopped working after restart. 
So he told that it must be a software issue, and there is no need for replacement of 
motherboard. Because it works randomly could there still be issue with motherboard ?
Anyone faced similar issue ?

Comment: Have you tried a different set of headphones?

Comment: yes. No headphones work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is still possible it can be the hardware.  The best way to tell is to create a Linux Live USB (here is [Ubuntu's](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)) and boot off of it.  If the audio jack works, then it is software.  If it does not, it is likely hardware.

Comment: I think a virtual box wont help right in this case ? I will have to create a linux live USB so it looks like a fresh start

Comment: @Amitwadhwa no a virtual machine will not help